# What is the simplest way to return multiple rows from table function in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, set-returning-functions

There is a table `my_table` that I want to query through a table function.

```
create table my_table (
  col_1 text,
  col_2 numeric
  // 10 more columns
);
```

According to documentation and articles in the Internet, there are several ways to do that. But most of them involve defining a row type duplicating the structure of the resulting table like
`create function ... returns table( col_1 text, col_2 numeric, ...)` in this case.

The simplest way I've found is as follows:

```
create or replace function my_func(p_x text)
   returns my_table
as
$$
  select * from my_table where col_1 = p_x;
$$
language sql;

--
select * from my_func('hello');
```

Unfortunately, it returns **only the first row** of the result, even though the query returns many. This is not what I expected.

If we change the function header to

```
create or replace function my_func(p_x text)
   returns table( col_1 text, col_2 numeric, /* and others */)
```

it works fine, but it would be great to avoid this duplication and reuse here the rowtype of `my_table`.

**How to define a function with table result having exactly same columns as in `my_table`?**

Comment: If an answer resolved your issue then please accept it. Accepting an answer helps future questioners having the same issue. Do not just leave an answered question open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the function as `returns setof my_table` to indicate that it returns a set, rather than just one row:

```
create or replace function my_func(p_x text)
   returns SETOF my_table
as
$$
  select * from my_table where col_1 = p_x;
$$
language sql;
```

Comment: Thank you for your brilliancy and blazing fast reaction.